# Ancient Jews eating only fish with fins and scales?

Tags: history, kashrut-kosher, fish

“[The Pentateuchal Dietary Proscription against Finless and Scaleless Aquatic Species in Light of Ancient Fish Remains](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/03344355.2021.1904675)” published in the peer-reviewed Tel Aviv archaeological journal on May 24, 2021, presents evidence from some 56 fishbone assemblages from 30 sites spanning from 1550 BCE to 640 CE.

“Significantly, all the fish assemblages from sites within the Southern Kingdom — first and foremost Jerusalem — presented evidence of modest to (more often) moderate amounts of scaleless fish remains,” they write.The requirement to eat only fish that has both fins and scales is found twice in the Torah: in Vayikrah 11: 9–12 and in Dvarim 14: 9–10.

**How can these findings be reconciled with the Torah's prohibitions to consume finless and scaleless fish?**

Comment: Before you worry about the fish, I bet they found a bunch of idols too!

Comment: "[The Pentateuchal Dietary Proscription against Finless and Scaleless Aquatic Species in Light of Ancient Fish Remains](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/03344355.2021.1904675)" at Taylor & Francis Online website

Comment: Except for the question itself (currently in bold), this question seems to be quoted (i.e. copied & pasted) from  "[Bad Judeans? Despite biblical ban, non-kosher fish were eaten in ancient Israel](https://www.timesofisrael.com/bad-judeans-despite-biblical-ban-non-kosher-fish-were-eaten-in-ancient-israel/)", from The Times of Israel website.

Comment: Times of Israel just posted an analysis with a rebuttal: https://www.timesofisrael.com/those-fishy-reports-on-ancient-israelites-eating-non-kosher-seafood/

Answer (score 5):

*How can these findings be reconciled with the Torah's prohibitions to consume finless and scaleless fish?*

To give  a few possible answers.

1. The research was biased and faulty
2. Finless and scaleless fish were used for purposes other than human consumption
3. If they were consumed, then perhaps they were consumed by the many non-Jewish residents of Eretz Yisreol at the time (Gerey Toshev)
4. Or they were consumed by those who sinned against kashrut Torah Laws and they were the crowd the Navi/Prophet gives instruction/correction to.
5. **BECAUSE** they weren't eaten there were so many of their remains left around. They were caught by the fishermen's nets with the Kosher fish and being that they weren't consumed and had far fewer marketplace buyers stuck around to have their remains being found today
6. Note the dates of these (merely) fifty six Fish assemblages from a mere thirty sites which weren't even all in Eretz Yisroel. It runs almost SIX HUNDRED YEARS after the destruction of the second Beis Hamikdush and the exiling of most of the Jewish population from Eretz Yisroel and predates the Jewish settlement in Eretz Yisroel by hundreds of years as well. No surprise that  they found non-kosher fish were eaten in Eretz Yisroel that time period.

etc. etc. etc.

Comment: 1, 5, and 6 seem more reflective of your not having read the original study than realistic proposals. I haven't read it either but I don't have any reason to think they didn't account for that

Comment: I did read  a few articles about what they are claiming  Having read  them I was struck by the weakness and vagueness of their claims.. If I'm going to assume they said something other then what their propagandists are saying they said and are basing themselves on  I have no reason to take them seriously  at all

Comment: "their propagandists" Pop-science journalism is not the propaganda machine of the Academy. Either critique the actual study or say the journalists didn't do it justice. Even a cursory scan of the original article reveals your point 6 is nonsense and they were well aware of the implications of the different subsets of the whole time period.

Comment: Regrading #5: According to "[Bad Judeans? Despite biblical ban, non-kosher fish were eaten in ancient Israel](https://www.timesofisrael.com/bad-judeans-despite-biblical-ban-non-kosher-fish-were-eaten-in-ancient-israel/)", in The Times of Israel, "_even in the holy, land-locked capital of Jerusalem, non-kosher fish remains were in evidence_".

Comment: @DoubleAA I read the entire study. One may conclude that the person who did the research was in fact biased. That's not really problematic itself, if one sticks to proper analysis of the data - we all have our biases, after all. One point that stuck out to me was the conclusion that the discoveries in the Kingdom of Judah are most likely reflective of a similar situation in the Kingdom of Israel, despite little to no research on the matter being done in sites identified with Israel.

Comment: Another point that stuck out was that there was no explanation - at least none that I saw - as to how it is known that these fish remains were indeed consumed. There was a note on how researchers know they were used for jewelry - yet the author did not seem to differentiate between different fish remains: Should we assume that they were all unpunctured, or not? Who knows? The author doesn't seem to clarify on the matter.

Comment: I also noticed that part of the study during the Roman period included studying fish remains at a time during which little to no Jews lived in Yerushalayim. I found that perplexing.

Comment: @DoubleAA Another point is that the author wrote that little-to-no scale-less fish remains were found in Tel Rechov and Tel Mikne (the latter one, at least, was a Plishti site (Ekron)), but there is little reason to conclude that this points to some sort of taboo. Based on what is this conclusion made? From my uneducated eyes, it seems to stem from the exact same reasoning that led scholars to believe for many years that the Israelite transfer from Canaanite writing to Phoenician writing was simultaneous across all of Israel, until this view was refuted about 12-13 years ago,

Comment: and the same for the transfer from bronze tools to iron ones.

Comment: Copy and paste and you have a full answer there.

Comment: @Mordechai while I do have a number of other points to make, I find Schmerel's answer perfectly okay (except perhaps for point 6). I'm just here backing him up.

Answer (score 3):

Writing in the Times of Israel ([here](https://www.timesofisrael.com/those-fishy-reports-on-ancient-israelites-eating-non-kosher-seafood/)), Joshua Berman and Ari Zivotofsky write that **these findings are actually highly in sync with the history of ancient Israel as told by the Prophets of the time**. The Jews who were eating non-kosher fish were the same as those who intermarried or who worshiped idols as described in Isaiah, Ezra and Nehemiah.

As @DoubleAA suggested in his comment to the question, "although the Torah proscribes idol worship, the prophets censure Israel for doing just this, and indeed **we find many dozens of figurines in Israelite sites during that time, including locations near where some of these non-kosher fishbones were found**."

The authors cite various archeological finds at different periods in time. Some from the city of David, dated to the 8th century BCE, found 5,385 fishbones with 96% of the fish remains from kosher fish. "Other sites in the City of David have a much higher percentage of non-kosher fishbones. Remarkably, again, these other sites date from the period just prior to the destruction of Jerusalem, broadly a period in which the residents of Judah come in for particularly harsh censure by the prophets of Israel."

Comment: Why are they writing in an off the beaten track news/blog site and not in a published journal

Comment: Did the prophets ever censure the people for eating catfish or any treif foods? If they still weren't eating pig for religious reasons why'd they give up on avoiding catfish?

Comment: @DoubleAA I am not them but (1) it is faster, (2) this is a very popular media at least in Israel and (3) the names of their authors speak for themselves Joshua Berman has an excellent recent book (https://www.amazon.com/Ani-Maamin-Criticism-Historical-Principles/dp/1592645380)

Comment: @DoubleAA Presumably because the original paper made waves owing to a write-up in the very same off the beaten track news/blog site

Answer (score -6):

Perhaps there were Jews who simply disobeyed Torah laws. King David violated Torah laws all his life. This does not prove that ancient Jews did not know about Torah laws.

The Rambam wrote:

> "when I have a difficult subject before me--when I find the road
> narrow, and see no other way of teaching a well-established truth
> except by pleasing one intelligent man and displeasing ten thousand
> fools--I prefer to address myself to the one man, and to take no
> notice whatever of the condemnation of the multitude; I prefer to
> extricate that intelligent man from his embarrassment and show him the
> cause of his perplexity, so that he may attain perfection and be at
> peace." — Guide, Preface

Comment: You propose an answer with the mitigating "perhaps" ("perhaps there were Jews who simply disobeyed Torah laws"), thereby granting that it may in fact be baseless but it is merely a suggestion rather than a statement of fact. You then submit the claim that "King David violated Torah laws all his life." This statement is unmitigated, but also unsubstantiated. What is the basis for this second assertion?

Comment: @robev While I generally disagree with Turk Hill's assumptions on various issues, with regards to Tanach study, I'm not aware of any obligation of accepting Chazal's interpretation of Tanach. There are many examples of great commentators who saw no problem with disagreeing with the Chazalic interpretation.

Comment: @Harel13 true but Turk Hill has spoken very disparagingly about King David in the past, more so than I think any great commentator would. It's all about attitude. Theirs is a negative one.

Comment: @robev Yes, I agree. There's p'shat, and then there's p'shat. Depends on your attitude, as you said.

Comment: @Harel13 Yes. According to RNS's new book Rationalism vs mysticism (which I'm currently reading now), Chazal was not infallible. However, their statements about Halakha are always binding for all Jews.

Comment: @Yehuda King David (although pious) made many sins. David sinned when he commanded the ordering of a census resulting in the murder of tens of thousands of Israelites by the enemy, his adulterous relationship with Bat Sheva and the murder of her husband and the soldiers who were with him speaks plainly enough that David was no Moses.

Comment: @Yehuda When I wrote "perhaps" I was responding to Dr. Yonatan Adler's claim that Jews did not know about the Torah. I was saying, "perhaps you are wrong, Dr. Adler." One should not rush to conclusions and say that this means the ancient Jews did not observe or know about the Torah. Adler himself says the absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.

Comment: @Yehuda Here is a link to the essay by Adler [here](https://www.timesofisrael.com/bad-judeans-despite-biblical-ban-non-kosher-fish-were-eaten-in-ancient-israel/?fbclid=IwAR1i7dOc7V7MQ3TXSuxY4DaScipP82FLgZ_dj8sLyZccaGsPUsMfcIjbsMo).

Comment: I would contend that there might be different traditions for kashrut laws. It always surprised me that Muslims could eat shellfish, but perhaps that was the tradition they received from us. Because they often admit that they received a lot from our traditions and they are comfortable relying on our kashrut, sometimes they rely on our kashrut more than theirs!